# MongoDB storing correct date but not showing correctly on Views(EJS)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs, ejs

I have a form where the user inputs a date using 

This is stored in a Mongo DB, the console log shows the date as correct (in ISODate("2017-05-21T00:00:00Z")), however, when passing this date as an argument in EJS, the date shown is different.

This is the data stored in mongoDB: "Begin" : `ISODate("2017-05-21T00:00:00Z")`

This is the data shown in EJS File: `'2017-05-20'`

I formatted the date using:

```
moment(data.Begin).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Without using moment, the date shown on EJS is:

```
"Sat May 20 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time (Mexico))"
```

which is wrong anyways.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB stores dates in UTC. Standard dates formats and the default for momentjs is "local time".

If you want to keep UTC then you ask for it, with `.utc()`

```
moment(data.Begin).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')');
```